# Asp.net MVC loading module and probing location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I'm currently building a plugin structure for my website. To load my assemblies I use Assembly.LoadFile. When I was dumping all dll's in my one plugin folder and set the probing privatePath to the plugin folder it was working.

To get the plugins a little more maintainable, I am trying to split up the plugins in separate folders. This gave me problems, because the probePath is only at the top level directory. I could add all plugin paths in that setting and it works, but I would rather that based on the directories found that the path is set dynamically. Is this possible? Or is there a way to set the path when loading the assembly?

Comment: Have you looked at Microsoft MEF?

Comment: Ehm... Looked at a lot of things. Any reason why you suggest this?

Comment: Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650670.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try Assembly.LoadFrom(string path)

It appears your original method really only pulls in assemblies in from normally probed places (GAC, and App directory)

Whereas the LoadFrom method allows you to specify assemblies in directories outside of this location

Either I had hit lucky when I had used this before or I had read and forgot about the differences.

Comment: I'll test it in a bit and let u know.

Comment: Assembly.LoadFrom does work, though then it is not in the probing directory and thus it cant find the views....

Comment: What is your structure?  I've devised a simple plug in architrcture before so should be able to help.

Comment: basically, I make a mvc area, add a ???plugin.cs file with some config. On preapplication init I load the files in the bootstrapper I initialize them. The only problem is, when the probepath is not set correctly, the compiled razorviews are not found.